# VBA: How can I disable some options from right-click context menu

Tags: excel, vba, controls

I need to

1)  Disable all the following options from "Cells" right-click context menu

```
a.  Paste options
b.  Insert
c.  Delete
d.  Format Cell
```

2)  Disable all the following options from "Columns" right-click context menu

```
a.  Paste options
b.  Insert
c.  Delete
d.  Clear Content
e.  Format Cell
```

3)  Disable all the following options from "Rows" right-click context menu

```
a.  Paste options
b.  Insert Copied Cells only (Not Insert)
c.  Format Cell
```

4)  Disable all the following options from "Rows" right-click context menu for a specific range of rows (e.g. Rows 1 to 3)

```
a.  Insert
b.  Delete
c.  Clear Content
```

5)  Disable all the following option from " Form control button " right-click context menu

```
a.  Format Control
```

Appreciate any help

Comment: Read this:   https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s6/win001.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple way to achieve what you want. For most of them you can use exactly what you see in the right click menu. For example for `Insert`, you see `Insert...`.

```
Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls("Insert...").Visible = True 'False
```

Similary for others. I have not found a way to disable `Paste Options:` or the icons in it. You can however disable the `Paste Special` under `Paste Options:` as I mentioned above using `Paste Special...`

**Note**: Well this is the least of your problems. Remember users can still use the Ribbon or shortcut keys to achieve those things which you disable ;)

**Edit**

> Unfortunately doesn't work for me. Does it have anything to do with Tables? because cells are part of a table! – Afshin Davoudy 8 mins ago

Yes for that you have to use

```
Application.CommandBars("List Range Popup").Controls("Delete").Visible = False
```

**BEFORE**

[image]

**AFTER**

[image]

> Afshin Davoudy: how can I disable options in "Column" context menue? or Rows? (From Extended Chat)

Use

```
Application.CommandBars("Column").Controls("Delete").Visible = False
Application.CommandBars("Row").Controls("Delete").Visible = False
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. should I put it in Worksheet_Activate() ?

Comment: You can but that will not solve the purpose becuase users can easily find a way around it. Also you will have to take care of it during the workbook open event since `Worksheet_Activate()` not trigger if the workbook opens with that sheet as the default sheet.

Comment: Where? On what line? You need to be precise

Comment: Your solution is just one line. I put it  in workbook_open, so the error is on that line!

Comment: I replaced "Insert" with "Delete" in your code. The error is gone but "Delete" option in the context menu is still active

Comment: Did you use "Delete" or "Delete..."?

Comment: `Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls("Delete...").Visible = False` This works

Comment: I just tried it and it works http://wikisend.com/download/550602/sample.xlsm

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work for me. Does it have anything to do with Tables? because cells are part of a table!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210143/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-afshin-davoudy).

Comment: i wasnt able to turn on the visibility so i did this:

    CommandBars("Column").Reset
    CommandBars("Column").Enabled = True